# Dotnet 6.0.12 runtime installed silently, cannot be managed by the control panel or Windows settings

Tags: c#, .net, .net-runtime

I have created a Windows software (desktop application) that runs on dotnet 6.0.12 runtime. So I install dotnet 6.0.12 silently via Wix Installer plugin, and it works fine. However, some users is installed dotnet runtimes but I cannot find or manage, or uninstall it in the control panel screen or the settings window (applications and features screen).

Please help me! why's it happen and how to fix it?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why is what happening and what do you actually want? The question is unclear. What does `some dotnet runtime client` mean? There's no `runtime client` and there can't be multiple minor runtime versions on the same machine. .NET (Core) 6 updates are distributed through Windows Updates. There aren't any breaking changes between point versions either. Your application should run fine even if it targets a newer point version until the machine gets updated

Comment: If you want to run on a *specific* point version, instead of silently installing you can publish a self-contained deployment or even a single executable. To check what .NET runtime is actually installed run `dotnet --version`. If that doesn't run, there's no .NET runtime on the machine. There may be other self-contained applications but you can't use their runtimes so they won't affect your application

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your feedback. My customer requires controlling the dotnet version and the installer is so small it's impossible.

Comment: Don't try to install it yourself then, let them do it. Whatever runtime already exists on the machines was put there by the customer, gets updated by the customer. Or create a self-contained deployment with the version they want. The question remains unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.